# SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2003 - " failed to initialize 0x84B10001"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on Windows Server 2003 and I get an error "failed to initialize 0x84B10001".

Googling got me the following link - http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27156/~/error%3A-%22configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-0x84b10001%22-when-attempting

However, my machine.config didn't contain the serviceModel entry at all - so this doesn't seem relevant to me. Any Idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by overwriting my `machine.config` in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` with `machine.config.default`

The difference between the 2 files was the following 2 lines were extra in my original machine.config

```
<section name="appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
<section name="connectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Once these lines were removed the install went through.